# Automated webtasks on javascript enabled webpages, using Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, http, cookies

I'm using Java.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to be able run automated tasks on the web. For example login to a site, do stuff there, fill out forms, logout etc.

I've already managed to do so (login and send comments) on simple sites where no javascript code is present (only html, html forms), by sending basic POST and GET messages using the HttpURLConnection class.

The problem is that I came across a site, that uses javascript code to generate session cookies (on the client side). So what happens is that when you access this site, javascript code gets executed in the browser, generating session cookies. Those cookies get sent with each request, without them, the site just won't function. (It is this site http://www.jofogas.hu/ )

I cannot get those cookies, because I do not know how to find out what Javascript code gets executed and I don't know how to run javascript code in Java and then use the results of that code.

Comment: From their javascript you can find `setNewSessionCookie` and see that it's based on vid cookie. I let you do the reverse engineering which isn't complex. You should ask for permission to script it.

Comment: @cyrbil How did you arrive to this conclusion? Did you use Chrome debugger tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the how:

First I saw that `set-cookie` header did not set any cookie named `ses` and this cookie magically appears. You know that in javascript, to set a cookie you call `document.cookie`. So I grabbed the source code, auto indent it, and search for `document.cookie`. You easily fall on `setNewSessionCookie` and you can see that it create a cookie named `ses`.

```
function setNewSessionCookie() {
    var b = get_vid();
    var d;
    var e;
    var a;
    var c = new Date();
    c.setTime(c.getTime());
    a = getCookie("ses");
    if (!a) {
        b = get_vid();
        if (!b) {
            return
        }
        d = (new Date()).getTime();
        a = b + "_" + d
    }
    e = new Date(c.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 15));
    document.cookie = name + "ses=" + a + ";expires=" + e.toGMTString()
}
```

This cookie is set with the value of the variable `a` which is set by `get_vid()`.

```
function get_vid() {
    var b;
    var a = getCookie("vsid");
    if (!a) {
        return false
    }
    if (a.search(",") == "-1") {
        b = Base64.decode(a)
    } else {
        b = a
    }
    return b.split(",")[0]
}
```

TL;DR: This function get the `vsid` cookie (which is send by set-cookie header), base64 decode it, and return the part before the coma. Next the `ses` cookie is created by appending `"_" + (new Date()).getTime()`

In my case:

```
getCookie("vsid") // "ODk5NjEwMzEsMTQzNDMwNDM4Ng=="
Base64.decode(getCookie("vsid")) // "89961031,1434304386"
getCookie("ses") // "89961031_1434304048406"
```

I warn you about legal issue on web scraping, it may be against the website terms of use (which are not in any language I speak ...).

**Edit:** For the question:

> Automated webtasks on javascript enabled webpages, using Java

You may be interessed in the [Selenium Project](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and their [java driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/#client-drivers)